# How to change orientation programmatically in Android

Tags: android, testing, android-emulator

I've tried the following:

```
Activity a = getActivity();
a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
Thread.sleep(2000);
a.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

on Android emulator. But it doesn't behave quite the same way as pressing Ctrl+F11 to rotate the screen manually.

So what is the correct way to change the orientation programmatically?

Comment: ctrl+F11 is working on a computer-monitor, while `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE/SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT` is the command for Android mobile screen (and it works!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be the right way to do it. It's your test that's broken.

First of all, don't use `Thread.sleep`, it'll freeze your entire App and will prevent anything from happening (including the orientation change). Try to use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) instead.

Secondly, the change will most likely not happen immediately, but only after you left `onCreate()` (and propably a couple of other [lifecycle methods](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle)).

Thirdly, if you change orientation your Activity will be [destroyed and recreated](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ConfigurationChanges). So you can't really switch back and forth within a single Activity instance.

Comment: So how can I programatically change the orientation, as if I was pressing Ctrl+F11 multiple times?

Comment: You use a Handler. Override its handleMessage method and post a delayed, empty message to it. In the method, look for the current orientation and toggle it.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Android emulator normally wouldnt rotate unless you manually rotate the device, the code you are actually using should work on a real device. Have you actually tried it in a real device?